# Get and Set Hide in viewport and Disable in viewport via Python API

Tags: python

In my plugin I have an operator that needs to iterate through potentially 100's of objects that might be 'hidden in viewport' or 'disabled in viewport' and perform some operations  that require the object to be visible in viewport. Afterwards I want to restore whatever visibility the object had, so I need to both get and set these options.

[image: Two icons] IE, get/set the status of these.

When I hover over the icons, both show the parameter `bpy.context.object.hide_viewport`. Obviously they can't both be the same parameter as they both do different things. How do I get and set 'hidden in viewport' and how do I get and set 'disabled in viewport' using the Python API?

Edit: I can see that both ObjectBase(bpy_struct) and Object(ID) have the `hide_viewport` property, however ObjectBase is documented as 'Temporarily hide in viewport' and Object is documented as 'Globally disable in viewports'. How do I access an Object's ObjectBase?

Comment: See https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Scene_and_Object_API (scroll to bottom)

Comment: Following that link to the release notes is not helpful.

Comment: Actually, it is.

Answer (score 7):

To iterate on the other answer which left out the get parts:

- [`bpy.context.active_object.hide_get()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=hide_get#bpy.types.Object.hide_get) - returns the visibility state (eye icon)
- [`bpy.context.active_object.hide_viewport`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.hide_viewport) - viewport visibility bool (monitor icon)

Note `hide_get` takes an optional [bpy.types.ViewLayer](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ViewLayer.html) argument if you want to get the visibility status of an object in a view layer that's not currently active.

Also note `obj.hide_viewport` invalidates any iteration upon a collection's `all_objects`. See https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_gotcha.html#collection-objects

Answer (score 5):

`bpy.context.active_object.hide_viewport = True` for MONITOR icon
`bpy.context.active_object.hide_set(True)` for EYE icon

for `collections` it's bit different
`bpy.context.collection.hide_viewport = True` will globally hide collection(MONITOR icon)
`bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children.get('Your_Collection_Name').hide_viewport = True` wil hide collectiob locally (EYE icon)

Comment: Calling `hide_set(True)` will still leave the object grayed out in the Outliner. Why?

Comment: @AndreasHaferburg Does object shows in viewport but grayed out in outliner? If you move your cursor in outliner then object should not be grayed out. This happens because blender does not draw particular area unless there are activity in that. You can redraw in code using `area.tag_redraw()`

Comment: I hide the object by clicking the eye icon in the outliner. Then I unhide using `hide_set(False)`. It becomes visible in the viewport, but it stays grayed out in the Outliner, even after clicking on another object in the Outliner.